# Unable to login in PDO

Tags: php

I couldn't find any solution, I can't login.It shows {"success":0,"message":"Login Failure"} which is fail. Can I know what is the problem with the code? Your help is much appreciated.

login.php

```
<?php

require("config.php");

if(!empty($_POST)){


    $query = "SELECT * FROM lecturer WHERE lecID = :lecID";

    $query_params=array(':lecID'=> $_POST['lecID']);

    try{
        $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
        $result=$stmt->execute($query_params);

    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        $response["success"]=0;
        $response["message"]="Database Error1. Please try again";
        die(json_encode($response));
        }

        $validate_info=false;
        //fetching rows from query
            $row = $stmt->fetch();

        if ($row){
            if($_POST['lecPass'] === $row['lecPass']){
                $login_ok==true;

            }

        }
        if($login_ok){
            //userLogin
            $response['success']=1;
            $response['message']="Login Successful";
            die(json_encode($response));

        }else{
            $response["success"]=0;
                $response["message"]= "Login Failure";
                die(json_encode($response));
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: User passwords are encrypted in DB Table or not? If yes, then you need to decrypt it and check with the POST value of password entered. And, Change `$login_ok==true;` to `$login_ok=true`;

Comment: you need to use `=` assignment operator instead of comparison operator `==`  $login_ok==true;

Comment: Thanks so much, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `=` `Assignment operator` instead of `comparison operator` `==`

```
$login_ok==true;
```

Change to

```
$login_ok=true;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing curly braces ("{" and "}") from PDO connection string-

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
```

When php replaces variable names in double quoted strings with variables, it does not affect the curly braces, so your connection string ends up looking like this-

```
"mysql:host={localhost};dbname={fypesyst_evaluation};charset=utf8"
```

complete with the curly braces, that make host and database name incorrect